# issue in gitolite

Tags: git, gitolite

I have installed the gitolite in the a machine which act as a git server. I have cloned that gitolite in my local machine. Configured some repositories and user rights. While making any changes in the gitolite.conf and pushing it, the changes are not taken into the gitolite.conf-compiled.pm file. Everytime I am manually correcting the changes in that file(gitolite.conf-compiled.pm). What is the issue here. Kindly clarify

Comment: What is the gitolite version you are using? It has recently changed (http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/g3why.html) Also what is the result of `git remote show -v` when executed within your local git-admin cloned repo?

Comment: When I am using "git remote show -v" it is showing the output as follows error: unknown switch `v'
usage: git remote show [<options>] <name>

    -n                    do not query remotes

Comment: But when I used "git remote show" it shows as origin. How to find the version of gitolite?

Comment: For the version of gitolite, try a simple ssh (as mentioned in http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/progit.html): Another convenient feature is what happens when you try and just `ssh` to the server. Gitolite shows you what repos you have access to, and what that access may be. Here's an example: `hello sitaram, this is git@git running gitolite3 v0.02-15-g1db50f4 on git 1.7.4.4`

Comment: hi thanks for ur prompt reply. When I used "git remote -v show" it shows as origin git@192.168.1.182:gitolite-admin (fetch)
origin git@192.168.1.182:gitolite-admin (push)

Comment: I got the version number. It shows like hello thillaiselvan, this is gitolite v2.3-32-ga8a3792 running on git 1.7.9.4

Comment: Your remote looks good. It might be an issue with the way gitolite got installed on the server. Plus, Gitolite V3 just got released (http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/g3why.html). Fixing the install by making a new upgraded one might be easier.

Comment: Oh, I have a small doubt. Whether need to change any things in the conf/ directory files? i.e example.conf example.gitolite.rc?

Comment: I confirm you don't need to change anything in the `example.xxx` files. But you need to edit `gitolite.conf` (which I believe you did), and then push back.

Comment: What did you do to make your `gitolite.conf-compiled.pm` updated properly?