# gitolite allows unauthorized user

Tags: git, gitolite

I have configured a repository and a group of users.
I have given read access for that repository to the group.

But when I logged in as a user who is not there in the group I am able to read the repository.
It lists that repository in the gitweb. Why it is behaving like this?

```
@all    = ganeshkumar hariharasubramanian karthigayan kiruthika kuppusamy lakshmanan manojkumar nvivek sathishkumar savithri thangappan thillaiselvan vennila
repo    gitolite-admin
        RW+     =   thillaiselvan

repo    test/thillaiselvan
        RW+     =   thillaiselvan
        R       =   @all

repo    others/admin_testing
                RW+             =   root nagalenoj thillaiselvan
```

Comment: Which version of gitolite are you using (see comments of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10207919/issue-in-gitolite) And Could you post the extract of your `gitolite.conf` with that declaration. Did you push back said `gitolite.conf`back to the gitolite-admin repo on the gitolite server?

Comment: gitolite version : v2.3-32-ga8a3792

Comment: yes I have pushed it back and the gitolite.conf-compiled.pm file got modified properly

Comment: Ok so still an old Gitolite V2 (time to upgrade to V3 ;) )

Comment: @VonC I have edited my post and added the contents of gitolite.conf for ur reference :)

Comment: Just realized you are the one asking about that "issue in gitolite" question. Did you make any progress on that other question? I suppose so, since your `gitolite.conf-compiled.pm` is updated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@all` is not the name of a valid group.

It is a special group allowing *any* user access to a repo (including special user `gitweb` by the way).
See Gitolite V3 (or 'g3') documentation (still valid for a Gitolite V2):
"[group definitions](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/groups.html)"

> #### special group `@all`
>
> `@all` is a special group name that is often convenient to use if you really mean "all repos" or "all users".

In other words, this is not a group you would define with

```
@all    = user1 user2 ...
```

It would be ignored. Adding @all to a repo means any user, even one not listed in the above definition, is granted access to said repo.

Comment: In that case, why is gitolite saying `remote: WARNING: possible undeclared group '@all'` when you use the `@all` group without defining it?

Comment: @OJW What version of gitolite are you using and what your gitolite.conf looks like? That could be a good question in its own for you to post on Stack Overflow.